# How do I left align these Bootstrap form items?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for the first time, and am having a lot of trouble aligning this form-horizontal to the left.

The list items are horizontal, as they should be, but I want the control-labels (the Bootstrap class for form labels) to all be at the same position floated left.

The form is contained in a div with a span of 7, as my site is two columns -- 7 and 4 columns.

Below is my HTML. If you look under "Horizontal Forms" on this page http://accounts.tao.tw.shuttle.com/examples_bootstrap/basecss/forms, you'll see that the labels are left aligned, but not absolutely left-aligned so that the beginning of the labels are at the same position vertically.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSaving">What are you saving for?</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputSaving" placeholder="e.g. Swimming Lessons, Birthday Party, College Fund, etc.">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="description">Add a short description</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="span4" rows="4" placeholder="Describe in your own words the saving goal for this piggybank"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="categoryselect">Choose a Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="span4">
                <!-- Add some CSS and JS to make a placeholder value-->
                <option value="Kittens">Kittens</option>
                <option value="Keyboard Cat">Keyboard Cat</option>
                <option value="Twitter Bird">Twitter Bird</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="goal">Your Saving Goal</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span4" id="goal">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is there no answer marked as correct for this question?

Answer (score 58):

Just my two cents. If you are using Bootstrap 3 then I would just add an extra style into your own site's stylesheet which controls the `text-left` style of the `control-label`.

If you were to add `text-left` to the label, by default there is another style which overrides this `.form-horizontal .control-label`. So if you add:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label.text-left{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Then the built in `text-left` style is applied to the label correctly.

Comment: or would you say the "left" answer... haha

Comment: 5 years later I truly believe this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @AntonioGonzález thanks! Crazy it was 5 years ago!

Answer (score 40):

If you are saying that your problem is how to left align the form labels, see if this helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/8gYPQ/

Try changing the text-align left / right in the CSS

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{
    /* text-align:right; */
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#ffa;
}
```

Comment: Updated the html and fixed the alignment of the submit button: http://jsfiddle.net/n3f25Lkd/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying a framework's source code directly, especially if you want to be able to keep it up to date – that is, unless you are willing to fork the repository and merge upstream code back in.

Comment: agreed that it's not a great idea to modify a frameworks source code @djule5, what I was suggesting is to add the above to the site's CSS so that it overrides the Bootstrap styling. Then you can update Bootstrap and not lose the customization, does that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of altering the original bootstrap css class create a new css file that will override the default style.

Make sure you include the new css file after including the bootstrap.css file.

In the new css file do

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{
   text-align:left !important; 
}
```

Comment: I would recommend never to use !important if there is an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Comment: Please use the solution by Tim B James below. important! is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

"pull-left" is what you need, it looks like you are using Bootstrap 2, I am not sure if that is available, consider bootstrap 3, unless ofcourse it is a huge rework! ... for Bootstrap 3 but you need to make sure you have 12 columns in each row as well, otherwise you will have issues.

Comment: "but you need to make sure you have 12 columns in each row as well, otherwise you will have issues" -- not true. If you have less than 12 columns defined, then your data will only consume the columns that you have defined, then the remaining columns will be blank. So, if you define a col-x-4, col-x-5, col-x-1, then the remaining 2 columns will be empty, and everything should work just fine. (Note, if you define MORE than 12 columns, then everything after the 12th column will wrap to the next line)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `style="text-align: left"` to your label.

Comment: eww!  avoid inline styles like this at all cost!  While it would work, it's bad practice, embedding styles into the html muddies the clear separations between data (html) and presentation rules (css).

Answer (score 1):

`text-align:left;` did not work for me but by adding `display:flex;` I was able to get the label to the left.

Answer (score -3):

I was having the exact same problem.  I found the issue within bootstrap.min.css.  You need to change the label:
`label {display:inline-block;}` to `label {display:block;}`